# How to execute X times a Job Executor step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

### Introduction

To keep it simple, let's imagine a simple transformation.
This transformation gets an input of 4 rows, from a Data Grid step.
The stream passes through a Job Executor, referencing to a simple job, with a Write Log component.

### Expectations

I would like the simple job executes 4 times, that means 4 log messages.

### Results

It turns out that the Job Executor step launches the simple job only once, instead of 4 times : I only have one log message.

### Hints

The documentation of [the Job Executor component](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Job+Executor) specifies the following :

> By default the specified job will be executed once for each input row.

This is parametrized in the "Row grouping" tab, with the following field :

> The number of rows to send to the job: after every X rows the job will be executed and these X rows will be passed to the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

The step actually works well : an input of X rows will execute a "Job Executor" step X times. The fact is I wasn't able to see it with the logs.

To verify it, I have added a simple transformation inside the "Job Executor" step, which writes into a text file. After I have checked this file, it appeared that the "Job Executor" was perfectly executed X times.

### Research

Trying to understand why I didn't have X log messages after the X times execution of "Job Executor", I have added a "Wait for" component inside the initial simple job. Finally, adding two seconds allowed me to see X log messages appearing during the execution.

[image: The trick to see every log]

Hope this helps because it's pretty tricky. Please feel free to provide further details.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, **as a side note**:

Pentaho is a set of programs (Spoon, Kettle, Chef, Pan, Kitchen), The engine is Kettle, and everything inside transformations is started in parallel. This makes log retrieving a challenging task for Spoon (the UI), you don't actually need a `Wait for` entry, try outputting the logs into a file (specifying a log file on the `Job executor` entry properties) and you'll see everything in place.

Sometimes we need to give Spoon a little bit of time to get everything in place, personally that's why I recommend not relying on Spoon Execution Results logging tab, it is better to output the logs to a DB or files.